# Get list of dicts from another python script?

Tags: python, stdout, ipc

I have a program where I need to call another py script from one py script and get a list of dicts from it. I've figured out how to call the other py script and get list as a string from stdout but how do I use it in the second script ?
Here is what the second script outputs.

```
 [{'itemkey1': 'item1', 'itemkey2': 'item2'}, {'itemkey1': 'item1', 'itemkey2': 'item2'}]
```

And I need this list in the first script. One solution I found is using `exec` but that brings up some security issues and since I would like to avoid it.

Comment: As soon as you use stdio for communication I assume that Your list of dicts shouldn't include custom class instances. Would You consider to use `json` for communication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `subprocess.check_output` to get the output from that script in a string and then apply `ast.literal_eval` to that string to get the dict object.

```
import ast    
import subprocess
ret = subprocess.check_output(['python','some_script.py'])
dic = ast.literal_eval(ret)
```

`ast.literal_eval` demo:

```
>>> ret = "[{'itemkey1': 'item1', 'itemkey2': 'item2'}, {'itemkey1': 'item1', 'itemkey2': 'item2'}]\n"
>>> ast.literal_eval(ret)
[{'itemkey2': 'item2', 'itemkey1': 'item1'}, {'itemkey2': 'item2', 'itemkey1': 'item1'}]
```

help on **ast.literal_eval**: `literal_eval(node_or_string)`

> **Safely** evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>       expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
>       Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
>       and None.

Answer (score 1):

`ast.literal_eval` is completely safe

```
>>> import ast
>>> output = "[{'itemkey1': 'item1', 'itemkey2': 'item2'}, {'itemkey1': 'item1', 'itemkey2': 'item2'}]"
>>> ast.literal_eval(output)
[{'itemkey2': 'item2', 'itemkey1': 'item1'}, {'itemkey2': 'item2', 'itemkey1': 'item1'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why not *import* the other script, and call a function from it to return you the data? That would return you a full python object instead of having to handle strings.

If you do want to pass structures around, I'd use the `json` module to serialize and deserialize the list of dictionaries:

```
print json.dumps(yourlist)
```

and

```
yourlist = json.loads(stdoutdata)
```

That'd make the output of your other script useful to more tools beyond Python.